# How to get an Aero feel in Ubuntu?

Tags: themes

Is it possible to get aero effect in Ubuntu 11.10 ? Just switched from Windows 7 64 bit and the looks are a bit classic in Ubuntu. Also any tips and tricks on appearance are most welcome. Thanks :)

Comment: What exact "Windows effects" do you want? Aero has several eye candy effects going on..

Answer (score 2):

Install Compiz Config Settings manager. Type this at the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

I am not sure if you have to enable certain repositories through the Ubuntu Software Center or not to do that. If so:

1. Launch the Software Center
2. click Edit --> Software Sources --> Click the [Other Software] Tab
3. and check Canonical Partners and Independent.

Then do this at the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You should then have some joy.

Launch the Compiz Config Settings manager by typing `ccsm` into the dash. Tweak away!

**WARNING**, do not enable Desktop Cube, as it will disable Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Likewise, do not uncheck Ubuntu Unity Plugin. There are some nice settings under the Ubuntu Unity Plugin though. My favorite effect is Wobbly Windows.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally rolled back the edit by @elboletaire. Fixed now.

Comment: Well at least you noticed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have make lot of theme changes to get a Windows like effect in Ubuntu. I will suggest you to try Kubuntu.. It has much better glassy effect than Windows. Kubuntu 11.10 is a solid release, with a snappy KDE 4.7. You will not be disappointed.